# Thermal throttling when laptop is cool?

Tags: laptop, cpu, cooling, temperature

I have a Lenovo Legion Y520 and the previous thermal paste done on it was awful, and I experienced thermal throttling all the time. As a result, I bought Grizzly's conductonaut and the results were oustanding; Temperatures were low and game performance was beyond what I could ask for.

A month and a half later I start getting weird thermal throttling issues, and instead of occurring consistently, they would occur at random times under 30 seconds. I managed to record one instance across ~45 seconds:

3 seconds
8 seconds
16 seconds
4 seconds
12 seconds

After opening Intel XTU tuning utility, I noticed that my Package temperature flctuates WILDLY. It goes from 100 to 89 to 94 to 62 to 75 to 58 back to 95-100. All in under 10 seconds.

Is my sensor broken? What's going on? Because the laptop itself seems very cool

Comment: Uneven thermal paste application resulting in sub-optimal die cooling? It should cause problems immediately, though.

Comment: I had it done professionally and even had it checked among other people who have done the job amazingly well. I was with him when he applied it and it took him around 2 hours to get it done (I'm aware it's a 20 minute job), so I'm confident it's not uneven thermal paste application. The laptop originally had an awful job done though, it was uneven and all over the place.